# imap disposition is null for attachment

Tags: imap, attachment, multipart, content-disposition

In our application we are reading the emails from Gmail using iMap and saving in DB, In email there are two attachments (one is pdf file and other is digital signature file).  For first file (pdf) I am getting disposition null  and not able to process the attachment but for second file (p7s) getting right disposition value as attachment.

Following is header information of attachments:

```
------=_NextPart_001_0025_01D03944.5B3A2140
Content-Type: application/pdf;
                name="USXMS III Draft PUS - VOPR # 15-814.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
                filename="USXMS III Draft PUS - VOPR # 15-814.pdf"


   ------=_NextPart_000_0024_01D03944.5B3A2140
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
```

Following is relevant code to process the attachments of email:

```
//Process attchements of email
protected processAttachments(def workItem, def message) {
    int attachmentCount = 0
    def content = message.content
    if (content instanceof Multipart) {
        for (cntr in 0..(content.count - 1)) {
            def bodyPart = content.getBodyPart(cntr)
            def disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition() 
            println("Disposition is " + disposition + ".");// returns null for pdf
            if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(disposition)) {
                if (this.saveAttachments(workItem, bodyPart)) {
                    attachmentCount++
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return attachmentCount
}
```

So in above code getDisposition returns null for pdf file. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What language?  What library?  Is it possible your library isn't handling multiline headers properly?

Comment: I am using Grails, using javax.mail, to parse the html content using jericho. Issue is why only pdf header can't be read and other attachments are fine.

Comment: Issue resolved as it was nested content. I have to loop through the content  to find attachment if disposition is null.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved as it was nested content. In case of disposition is null I have to loop through the content to find attachment(s).